# Periodic crash with Ubuntu Server 20.04 on Raspberry Pi 3 B+

Tags: 20.04, crash

### The setup

I am finally decided to ask for help about an issue that started a couple weeks ago.
I am running a headless RPI 3B+ with Ubuntu Server 20.04, running mainly a Wireguard server and a couple of lightweight Docker containers (Homebridge, Pi-hole, Portainer etc).

### My investigation

For a couple of weeks now (no exact date or action that started the issue) the Pi becomes randomly unaccessible over the network until hard-rebooted. After further investigation, here's what I can report:

- No particular overload at any point that could crash the Pi, power levels are always good, power supply is brand new and definitely outputting enough power.
- When the crash happens, the Pi is unreachable from the network, but continues to run: on-screen console is still visible, Dockers still run in the background according to later retrieved syslog, and activity LED occasionally lights-up.
- The on-screen console shows an error message (attached [here](https://cloud.cilusse.com/s/BwHGFo8KMWxQLYT))
- Syslog says the following:

```
Dec 15 18:07:51 rpi kernel: [47182.438053] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Dec 15 18:07:51 rpi kernel: [47182.438136] NETDEV WATCHDOG: eth0 (lan78xx): transmit queue 0 timed out
Dec 15 18:07:51 rpi kernel: [47182.438270] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 0 at net/sched/sch_generic.c:447 dev_watchdog+0x370/0x378
Dec 15 18:07:51 rpi kernel: [47182.438276] Modules linked in: xt_nat xt_tcpudp veth xt_conntrack nf_conntrack_netlink nfnetlink xfrm_user xfrm_algo xt_addrtype br_netfilter bridge stp llc iptable_nat xt_MASQUERADE nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 ip6table_filter ip6_tables iptable_filter bpfilter wireguard ip6_udp_tunnel udp_tunnel aufs overlay dm_multipath scsi_dh_rdac scsi_dh_emc scsi_dh_alua btsdio bluetooth ecdh_generic ecc brcmfmac brcmutil cfg80211 bcm2835_codec(CE) bcm2835_isp(CE) bcm2835_v4l2(CE) v4l2_mem2mem bcm2835_mmal_vchiq(CE) videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_dma_contig snd_bcm2835(CE) videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 snd_pcm raspberrypi_hwmon videobuf2_common snd_timer videodev snd mc vc_sm_cma(CE) uio_pdrv_genirq uio sch_fq_codel drm ip_tables x_tables autofs4 btrfs zstd_compress raid10 raid456 async_raid6_recov async_memcpy async_pq async_xor async_tx xor xor_neon raid6_pq libcrc32c raid1 raid0 multipath linear crct10dif_ce spidev phy_generic aes_neon_bs aes_neon_blk crypto_simd cryptd 
Dec 15 18:07:51 rpi kernel: [47182.438514] CPU: 1 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/1 Tainted: G         C  E     5.4.0-1025-raspi #28-Ubuntu
Dec 15 18:07:51 rpi kernel: [47182.438521] Hardware name: Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Plus Rev 1.3 (DT)
Dec 15 18:07:51 rpi kernel: [47182.438529] pstate: 60400005 (nZCv daif +PAN -UAO)
Dec 15 18:07:51 rpi kernel: [47182.438539] pc : dev_watchdog+0x370/0x378
Dec 15 18:07:51 rpi kernel: [47182.438547] lr : dev_watchdog+0x370/0x378
Dec 15 18:07:51 rpi kernel: [47182.438554] sp : ffff80001000bd80
Dec 15 18:07:51 rpi kernel: [47182.438559] x29: ffff80001000bd80 x28: ffff0000363a4380
Dec 15 18:07:51 rpi kernel: [47182.438569] x27: 00000000ffffffff x26: ffff00002bf0f680
Dec 15 18:07:51 rpi kernel: [47182.438579] x25: ffffd97df4309018 x24: ffff00002bf0f740
Dec 15 18:07:51 rpi kernel: [47182.438588] x23: ffff0000352cf45c x22: ffff0000352cf000
Dec 15 18:07:51 rpi kernel: [47182.438598] x21: ffff0000352cf480 x20: ffffd97df4607000
Dec 15 18:07:51 rpi kernel: [47182.438607] x19: 0000000000000000 x18: 0000000000000000
Dec 15 18:07:51 rpi kernel: [47182.438616] x17: 0000000000000000 x16: 0000000000000000
Dec 15 18:07:51 rpi kernel: [47182.438626] x15: ffff000035a322f0 x14: ffffffffffffffff
Dec 15 18:07:51 rpi kernel: [47182.438636] x13: 0000000000000000 x12: ffffd97df4742000
Dec 15 18:07:51 rpi kernel: [47182.438646] x11: ffffd97df462c000 x10: ffffd97df4742a80
Dec 15 18:07:51 rpi kernel: [47182.438655] x9 : 0000000000000000 x8 : 0000000000000004
Dec 15 18:07:51 rpi kernel: [47182.438663] x7 : 0000000000000000 x6 : 0000000000000000
Dec 15 18:07:51 rpi kernel: [47182.438672] x5 : 0000000000000000 x4 : 0000000000000002
Dec 15 18:07:51 rpi kernel: [47182.438681] x3 : ffffd97df3c15790 x2 : 0000000000000040
Dec 15 18:07:51 rpi kernel: [47182.438689] x1 : 0000000000000000 x0 : 0000000000000000
Dec 15 18:07:51 rpi kernel: [47182.438699] Call trace:
Dec 15 18:07:51 rpi kernel: [47182.438708]  dev_watchdog+0x370/0x378
Dec 15 18:07:51 rpi kernel: [47182.438720]  call_timer_fn+0x40/0x1e8
Dec 15 18:07:51 rpi kernel: [47182.438729]  run_timer_softirq+0x1d4/0x590
Dec 15 18:07:51 rpi kernel: [47182.438738]  __do_softirq+0x170/0x424
Dec 15 18:07:51 rpi kernel: [47182.438748]  irq_exit+0xb4/0xe8
Dec 15 18:07:51 rpi kernel: [47182.438760]  __handle_domain_irq+0x74/0xc8
Dec 15 18:07:51 rpi kernel: [47182.438768]  bcm2836_arm_irqchip_handle_irq+0x78/0xf0
Dec 15 18:07:51 rpi kernel: [47182.438775]  el1_irq+0x108/0x200
Dec 15 18:07:51 rpi kernel: [47182.438784]  arch_cpu_idle+0x40/0x238
Dec 15 18:07:51 rpi kernel: [47182.438793]  default_idle_call+0x28/0x6c
Dec 15 18:07:51 rpi kernel: [47182.438805]  do_idle+0x214/0x2a0
Dec 15 18:07:51 rpi kernel: [47182.438813]  cpu_startup_entry+0x2c/0x78
Dec 15 18:07:51 rpi kernel: [47182.438825]  secondary_start_kernel+0x18c/0x1c8
Dec 15 18:07:51 rpi kernel: [47182.438833] ---[ end trace 8fa731254680f7cd ]---
```

- A simple reboot restores full functionality
- The crash seems to be happening ever day and a half or so (don't know yet if it always is an exact time)
- Being busy this week, I tried a temporary workaround by scheduling a daily software reboot at 4 am, possibly preventing the Pi from crashing, but without success. It seems like a full power-cycle is required.

### My understanding

From what I understand, the issue comes/affects eth0 along with its linked modules, which would  explain the impossibility to remote into the Pi, but the services still working.
Other than that, I am not sure which steps to take towards resolving the problem, any help would be greatly appreciated. Also let me know if I need to attach more logs.

**Thank you very much for reading me, and let's resolve this!**

_cilusse

Comment: your tainted kernel codes indicate an unsigned module has been loaded. Look there to start with.

Comment: After a bit of research, I get what a tainted kernel is, but I never intended to do it. My system is just a normal Ubuntu Server 20.04 with only packages coming from apt. How would I go about finding out what made it tainted ? And if this thing really is the cause of the crash ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1861936. A fix is coming shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Issue seems to have disappeared after an update!
Glad it works, if anyone encounters the same problem, keep your system up to date for the next couple of weeks and it might very much get fixed.

All the best,

...edit:
The issue is back, they are working on a fix.